# Azure Spatial Anchors - How to get multiple Anchors

Tags: ios, swift, azure-spatial-anchors

I tried the Azure Spatial Anchor for iOS (Swift) and it worked fine. I can add and retrieve single Anchor but now I want to retrieve multiple Anchors.

Answer (score 0):

This same question was cross-posted to GitHub and answered there: https://github.com/Azure/azure-spatial-anchors-samples/issues/325